# Amplify cloudfront cache for one page in nextjs app

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

how to use amplify.yml or customHttp.yml for caching only one page in nextjs? There is pattern for css or js. How to write cache control for only one page like domain.com/category/[slug]?

```
customHeaders:
  - pattern: '**/*.css'
    headers:
      - key: Cache-Control
        value: 'public,max-age=31536000,immutable'
  - pattern: '**/*.js'
    headers:
      - key: Cache-Control
        value: 'public,max-age=86400'
```